# laravel dynamic field from linked model, based on another model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am in a situation where I want to get the **form** for each team of based on competition

`Team` model

```php
public function standing()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Standing::class);;
}
```

`Competition` model

```php
public function standing()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Standing::class);;
}
```

- Each `Team` has many `Standing`
- Each `Competition` has many `Standing`

standing table

- team_id
- competition_id
- form

my code

```php
$f = Fixture::where('status', 'NS')
            ->with('teamA', 'teamB', 'competition')
            ->get();
```

since all fixtures of all competitions are coming, but once team can be in two competition,
hence its form is different.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Leicester vs Newcastle",
    "team_a": {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Leicester",
      **"form": null**
    },
    "team_b": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Newcastle",
      **"form": null**
    },
    "competition_id": 1,
    "competition": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Premier League",
    },
  },
  {
    "name": "Leeds vs Tottenham",
    "id": 344,
    "team_a": {
      "id": 19,
      "name": "Leeds",
      "form": null
    },
    "team_b": {
      "id": 11,
      "form": null
    },
    "competition_id": 2,
    "competition": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Other League",
    },
  },
]
```

I have tried to explain the situation,
can someone please tell me how to get this?

for ex.
in champions league(competition), man. united has form WWWLDW, but same team in another league might be different

Comment: what did u mean

Comment: I think your db structure could be simplified. I mean, you store the "form" in the column, but that will always change right? Also, that depends on the latest X games of that specific competition I guess. I think you could just store in your `fixtures` table the `home_team`, `away_team`, `competition_id`, `status` and in order to get the form you could calculate it on the flight with a sub query to fetch the result of the latest matches for each team. By the way, you could improve your description clarifying what "form" is since the beginning. In coding context it may cause confusion.